# Execution time surpassed while traversing through a list of values

Tags: python, execution-time

I'm working through a challenge to see if a given sequence is strictly increasing if one and only one element is removed from it.  The output should be a **True** or **False**.  This is my code:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):

    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        element = sequence[i]
        del sequence[i]

        if all(i < j for i, j in zip(sequence, sequence[1:])):
            return True

        sequence.insert(i, element)

    return False
```

It works most of the times but there are 2 problems with this code:

1. The output is **undefined** when these are the inputs: `[30, 60, 50, 80, 100, 200, 150]`, `[1000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 5000]`
2. The execution time is surpassed when this is the input:  `[-9996, -9995, -9994, -9993, -9991, -9989, -9987, -9986, -9985, -9983, -9982, -9980, -9978, -9977, -9976, -9975, -9974, -9972, -9968, -9966, -9965, -9961, -9957, -9956, -9955, -9954, -9952, -9948, -9942, -9939, -9938, -9936, -9935, -9932, -9931, -9927, -9925, -9923, -9922, -9921, -9920, -9919, -9918, -9908, -9905, -9902, -9901, -9900, -9899, -9897, -9896, -9894, -9888, -9886, -9880, -9878, -9877, -9876, -9874, -9872, -9871, -9870, -9869, -9868, -9867, -9865, -9857, -9856, -9855, -9854, -9853, -9852, -9851, -9849, -9848, -9846, -9845, -9843, -9842, -9841, -9840, -9837, -9834, -9828, -9826, -9824, -9823, -9820, -9816, -9814, -9812, -9811, -9810, -9809, -9807, -9806, -9804, -9803, -9801, -9800]`

My guess is that the fact that my code being resource-intensive isn't the only thing wrong with it, as the inputs in #1 were quite small.  However, I don't know what it could be.

Comment: Challenges like this invariably require you to find a more clever solution than trying every possible sequence.

Comment: Search the list for the first element that's not in order. Then check that the rest of the list is in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def strictly_increasing_but_one(sequence):
    sequence = np.array(sequence)

    # The differences should always be positive 
    # if we have a strictly increasing sequence
    differences = np.diff(sequence)
    if (differences <= 0).sum() > 1:
        # We found more than one element which is smaller 
        # than the previous element
        return False

    # However, it could be that there were elements which were 
    # greater than their predecessors but still lower than their 
    # pre-predecessors (check test4 for an example). Hence, we need to
    # remove the previously found smaller elements and check again:
    keep = np.insert(differences > 0, 0, True)
    differences = np.diff(sequence[keep])
    return (differences <= 0).sum() == 0

test1 = [30, 60, 50, 80, 100, 200, 150]
test2 = [1000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 5000]
test3 = [-9996, -9995, -9994, -9993, -9991, -9989, -9987, -9986, -9985, -9983, -9982, -9980, -9978, -9977, -9976, -9975, -9974, -9972, -9968, -9966, -9965, -9961, -9957, -9956, -9955, -9954, -9952, -9948, -9942, -9939, -9938, -9936, -9935, -9932, -9931, -9927, -9925, -9923, -9922, -9921, -9920, -9919, -9918, -9908, -9905, -9902, -9901, -9900, -9899, -9897, -9896, -9894, -9888, -9886, -9880, -9878, -9877, -9876, -9874, -9872, -9871, -9870, -9869, -9868, -9867, -9865, -9857, -9856, -9855, -9854, -9853, -9852, -9851, -9849, -9848, -9846, -9845, -9843, -9842, -9841, -9840, -9837, -9834, -9828, -9826, -9824, -9823, -9820, -9816, -9814, -9812, -9811, -9810, -9809, -9807, -9806, -9804, -9803, -9801, -9800]
test4 = [1000, 2000, 1500, 1800, 5000]

strictly_increasing_but_one(test1) # False
strictly_increasing_but_one(test2) # False
strictly_increasing_but_one(test3) # True
strictly_increasing_but_one(test4) # False
```

**Explaination**: Imagine you have a strictly increasing sequence of numbers, then the difference between each element and the previous element should always be positive:

```
for all x[i]: x[i] > x[i-1]
```

All elements which are lower than their previous element, would cause negative differences. We can calculate the differences with [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and then check how many of them are negative. If we find more than one, we know that there are at least two elements which we would need to remove to make the sequence strictly increasing (this is covered by the if-statement).

However, there could still be elements that are greater than their immediate predecessors but lower than the elements before (see `test4`). Hence, we remove the *disturbers* from before and check again whether we find any negative differences. If we don't, we can be sure that the sequence is now strictly increasing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this more?

Comment: Actually, there was a mistake in my old answer since it did not cover this sequence `[1000, 2000, 1500, 1800, 5000]`. I added more comments to explain my code.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to test if a value at index + 1 is greater than the value at index, and this can be done all at once using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# three examples
a = [30, 60, 50, 80, 100, 200, 150]
b = [1000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 5000]
c = [-9996, -9995, -9994, -9993, -9991, -9989, -9987]

for test in [a, b, c]:
    test = np.array(test)
    result = np.all(test[1:] > test[:-1])
    print(result)
```

gives:

```
False
False
True
```

you can put this test in a function that drops one element at a time from a test sequence, to replace your original function.

```
def test_seq(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
        test = np.array(seq[:i] + seq[i+1:])
        if not np.all(test[1:] > test[:-1]):
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `length of longest increasing subsequence` of the given array and if that length is `equal or one less than the total length of the array` then the answer will be `True` either it will be `False`.

You can find the `Longest Increasing Subsequence` using `DP in N-square` or by `Divide and Conquer method in N log N`.

Comment: "You can find the Longest Increasing Subsequence using DP in N-square or by Divide and Conquer method in N log N."

Could you elaborate on this?